# What is the one-to-one correspondence between a set of complex numbers and positive numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to think of a mapping between these two sets:

$V = \{z = e^{i\alpha} | i^2 = -1, \alpha \in [0, \pi]\}$

$W = \{w |w \in [0; +\infty] \in R \}$

Could somebody please give a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some sense, the sets $V$ and $W$ are "smooth", and finding a map between the two is easier when you try to find a way to layer $W$ on top of $V$. Here's what I mean-

$V$ is a semicircle in the complex plane, and $W$ is a line in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$. Think of the semicircle as an infinitely stretchable elastic band that begins at $0$ and ends at $\pi$, and try to layer it on top of $W$.

You'll find a map $f:V \to W$ which maps $0$ to $0$ and $\pi$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you want this map to exhibit some special features. Otherwise,
$\phi : W \rightarrow V, w \mapsto e^{i\pi\tanh(w)}$ does the job smoothly. Sigmoids are also good candidates to replace the hyperbolic tangent.